# How to get the iframe url for specific domain in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My WordPress WebSite Posts has different type of iframe tags:
eg:

```html
<iframe src="http://examplesite1.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://examplesite2.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://examplesite3.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://examplesite4.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
```

I Need WordPress Function for get and replace iframe src for specified (eg: examplesite3.tld) domain eg:

```html
<iframe src="http://examplesite1.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://examplesite2.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
<iframe src="/embed.php?ref=http://examplesite3.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://examplesite4.tld/somepageordirectory"></iframe>
```

I'm new in WordPress.

Any Help is Highly appreciated and a lot of sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0):

We need the surrounding code to understand how the page is built, not the displayed code.

To do what you're talking about you would use the surrounding html tags and echo the wordpress variable within it, eg:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo wp_function( 'variable' );?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Because my site has a lot of iframe tags so i need any wordpress/php function which work as find and replace eg: `function replace_content($content)
{
$content = str_replace('##Replace Me##', '##With Something Else##',$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');` 
But it will only for fixed string not with variable.

Comment: Can you set a class or id to the iframe you want to replace the link on? If you can then you can do it easily, either with the php or even a dom replace using Javascript once the page has loaded.

Comment: If it is on a specific iframe you could iterate through the number of iframe tags, but that is messy

Comment: By using bellow wp function,i will able dynamicaly add id to the specified iframe eg: 
`function replace_content($content)
{
$content = str_replace('src="http://examplesite3.tld', 'id="myembed" src="http://examplesite3.tld',$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');`
Now how do i get and replace url in server side (wp-function or php) as i asked in question?